# POST data with PHP only

Tags: php

I have tried to post the following data with PHP without HTML

```
    <form class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE" />
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
        <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Customer's First Name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Customer's Last Name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456" / >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment"/>
    </form>
```

What I have tried is:

```
$response = httpPost("payments.php",
array(
  'cmd'      => '_xclick',
  'no_note'      => '1',
  'lc'      => 'DE',
  'bn'      => 'PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest',
  'first_name'      => 'Customers First Name',
  'last_name'      => 'Customers Last Name',
  'payer_email'      => 'customer@example.com',
  'item_number'      => '123456',
   'submit'      => 'Submit Payment')
);

function httpPost($url, $data){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

... but this method not works - I only see a white page when I echo the response.

Comment: A url is more than a filename. It needs a path, perhaps a protocol and a domain.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have tried it now with the URL and it still shows nothing.

Comment: check error log and [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php), do you have curl installed?

Comment: OK, just checking, do you actually echo the `$response` you get? You say so, but it never hurts to double-check. You could try the URL in your browser, and make sure the `payments.php` page responds with something when no post fields are supplied.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In error log, there is nothing und curl_error shows "Operation completed without any errors"

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I have tried only the URL and I get a redirect to a page (PayPal)... So maybe fyi: Payments.php is the file to make a transaction to paypal. And I am echoing the $response with echo $response at the end (after the fuction declaration of httpPost)

Comment: Ah well, if `payment.php` only does a redirect, it might not have any real output. You should know that cURL does not respond to a redirect header response, or javascript redirect, in its current state.

Comment: Ah, alright. Nice to know, that makes sense... Do you maybe have a solution how I can solve my problem with a other technique?

Comment: I assume that `payment.php` is under your control? In that case, why do you want to use cURL? You could just modify `payment.php` to do what you want.

Comment: This is a very good idea, thank you very much! @KIKOSoftware